# Changes in Rails fixtures are not propagated through to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, fixtures

In Rails 4.2.1, I have a `Book` model. I also have `BookAcl`model that `belongs_to` to `Book`. In my test, I load both through fixtures defined in `tests/fixtures`. In my test, in `setup`, I instantiate both objects based on the fixture data. Up to this point everything works fine.

In my test, I modify the BookAcl object and expect these changes to be reflected when accessing the same BookAcl through the Book object. However that is not happening. In fact when I look (via Pry) at the BookAcl object, the properties are different than the Book.BookAcl object, even though the rest of the object is identical.

What am I doing wrong? How I force these changes to propagate through the object graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `#reload`. There is no [Identity Map](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.5/classes/ActiveRecord/IdentityMap.html) in current version of Rails (they decided it produced too much bugs), so you should manually re-fetch all objects you wish by calling `#reload` whenever DB record changes.

Comment: Huh, thanks for that. So what would be the correct approach for verifying things in a test? Refetch after every expected object change? Gross...

Comment: Well, it's correct to `#reload` after you need to check object for something in a test/spec. It might be possible that you will benefit from splitting your tests in smaller pieces (splitting single test case into several test cases), if it is true that you repeat change-check cycle many times in a single test case.